# KDE 22.04 X11 VNC Alt Shift Tab not performing Walk Through Windows (Reverse) Task Switcher

Tags: linux, xorg, vnc, kde, alt-tab

Alt+Shift+Tab will not switch tasks in reverse when I VNC into my Linux box from my Windows machine. It has something to do with backtab. My settings show that Alt_Shift+Backtab is set for reverse operation. Backtab is typically Shift+Tab. But the translation to backtab seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work properly, I remove the translation for backtab (Shift+Tab or
ISO_Left_Tab) in the X11 keyboard settings on the Linux box.

Modify /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc

From:

```
key  <TAB> {        [ Tab , ISO_Left_Tab    ]       };
```

To:

```
key  <TAB> {        [ Tab                   ]       };
```